# Issue running driver.find_elements_by_class_name

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

https://www.oddsportal.com/profile/Keenz/my-predictions/next/

In a first block I get a dict of PICK indexes for every events.
[image]

In a first block I get a list of events links for every matches.
[image]

In a third block I go to event link and try to click on a "plus". 
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/serie-b/criciuma-brasil-de-pelotas-61ZV2RDN/#ah;3;-1.00;0

[image]

For this action I try to get a list of "plus" and try to choose , but I get empty list.

```
def parse(driver, request):
    driver.get("https://www.oddsportal.com/profile/Keenz/my-predictions/next/")

    # Get indexes of PICK
    picks_dict = {}
    picks = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('pred-usertip')
    for pick_ind, pick in enumerate(picks):
        tds = pick.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        for ind, td in enumerate(tds):
            if td.text:
                picks_dict['pick'+str(pick_ind)] = ind

    #Get links to events
    odds = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('number2')
    odds_list = []
    for odd in odds:
        odds_list.append(odd.get_attribute('href'))

    #Pick a "plus"
    for ind in range(len(odds_list)):
        if ind != 0:
            driver.get(odds_list[ind])
            print(driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ico-add'))    #[]
            driver.find_elements_by_class_name('ico-add')[picks_dict['pick'+str(ind)]].click()  #IndexError

    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might not be working if there is more than just `ico-add` in the classname. You could try running a `contains` query on the classname instead.

I navigated to your page and ran the following code with success, retrieving 2 elements in `plus_icons_list`:

```
plus_icons_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'ico-add')]")
```

[image]

Comment: It’s strange. After all, the class there is `ico-add`

Comment: I have had mixed results with find_elements_by_class_name. Sometimes when you hover an element with mouse, its class attributes will change. So calling find_by_class_name will not work if anything besides `ico-add` is in there. This is why I prefer contains query. Let me know if this resolves your issue.

Comment: On this page I get only two items - https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/serie-b/criciuma-brasil-de-pelotas-61ZV2RDN/#1X2;3

Comment: I have tested the same XPath against the page link you just provided, and I am getting 3 elements. You may have to wait for them to exist first -- `wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'ico-add')]")))`